# kernel - char device access

Tags: kernel, linux-device-driver

I am writing a char device which need to use another char device (one that we wrote too).
open, ioctl are used by userspace, so probably the access is done in other method.
How does my new custom char device should access another char device   ?

Thanks,
Ran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said module A will use module B and they are written by you.

Let me suppose you have two modules whose names are A and B.

You can directly call functions in module B from module A if you have already exported functions in module B using `EXPORT_SYMBOL`, which exports given function to the global name space of the kernel.

In addition, module B should be loaded prior to module A because module A has a dependency on module B.

For more information, I would recommend you to search google with [linux intermodule communication](https://www.google.co.kr/#q=linux+intermodule+communication).